# Could not roll back JDBC transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed

Tags: java, hibernate, connection

I have this method when cron scheduler run the process I have received the "Could not roll back JDBC transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed."

Please let me know about this solution. Also, ask me for more details if any.

```
@Override
public void updatePOCustStatus(List<PoOrderPojo> openPoList) {

    Session session = null;
    String uptQuery = "";

    for(PoOrderPojo poJsonObj : openPoList)
    {
        try {
            session = hibernateSession.openSession();

            session.beginTransaction();
            uptQuery = "UPDATE plm_purchase_order_mt SET po_cust_edi= 'T', po_cust_edi_on = NOW() WHERE po_id ="+poJsonObj.getPoId();

            logger.info("uptQuery = "+uptQuery);

            int totalUpdate = session.createSQLQuery(uptQuery).executeUpdate();
            session.getTransaction().commit();

            if (totalUpdate > 0) {
                logger.info("Updated poCustEdi as T to the "+poJsonObj.getPoId()+" , status =" + totalUpdate);
            } else {
               logger.info("Failed to updated poCustEdi as T to the "+poJsonObj.getPoId()+" , status =" + totalUpdate);
            }
        }catch (HibernateException ex) {
            logger.error(AppException.getStackTrace(ex));
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }finally{
            hibernateSession.closeSession(session);
        }
        uptQuery = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378747/nhibernate-transaction-commit-automatically-closes-session
Committing a transaction will close the associated session.

Comment: Could you please explain more. I'm new to this.